# How do I clear cookies on Expo AuthSession.startAsync on Android

Tags: android, react-native, cookies, expo

I am running into issues on Android where I can not get back to the login screen for external logins when using AuthSessions.startAsync once I am signed in.

This allows me in once, but then I always just get logged straight back in again rather than being prompted for which account to log in with.

I have no need with my app to eject, so I really do not want to unless I really have to.

I've read from the following link that this is possible.

https://medium.com/@manoj_makkuboy/clear-cookies-in-react-native-expo-without-ejecting-8cc964c0a4b7

By running this code:

```
var RCTNetworking = require("RCTNetworking");
RCTNetworking.clearCookies(() => {});
```

This seems to work on IOS (Which doesn't have the same issue), but not on Android, on Android clearCookies is undefined, although the RCTNetworking is bringing back something.

Does anyone have any idea how I can overcome this issue?

currently i'm using

`"expo": "^32.0.5"`
and
`"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz"`

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this @user3284707?

Comment: I did not :-( I did manage to find a half solution to always prompt for the users credentials on my MVC project when it calls Google and Facebook to half solve my issue, but the actual question I was unable to find a solution