# expo AuthSession.startAsync does not redirect to universal login after the first success

Tags: expo, auth0

I am building an [expo app](https://github.com/ocdexperience/auth0-example) that leverages auth0 for authentication.

I have trouble switching to another account after I have successfully logged in and logged out. The details reproduce steps are:

1. Pull the project, `yarn install && expo start --ios`
2. (Optional) For your safety, replace `auth0ClientId` and `auth0Domain` in App.js with your own auth0 info
3. Press "Log in with Auth0", get a prompt, and finally see something like below [image]
4. Log in with gmail (there should be such an option, even though it is not in this picture)
5. If you successfully log in, you should be able to see "You are logged in, !"
6. Press "Log out"
7. If you try to redo step 3-4, you are no longer able to see the universal login page as shown in the picture. Instead, you are logged in directly.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405829/how-do-i-clear-cookies-on-expo-authsession-startasync-on-android) describes the same behavior but he assumes it is client that caches the authentication info in cookie. I don't think this is the reason. I believe auth0 caches the first logged in user on server side and return the cached result regardless. My evidence: I add this `console.log` at https://github.com/ocdexperience/auth0-example/blob/master/App.js#L68 and every time I try to log in, this line always print that's why I guess `await AuthSession.startAsync({ authUrl })` returns the cached result directly.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are being logged in via silent authentication. This does indeed use a session cookie. To fully logout the user you must clear the cookie, or use the recommended method of utilizing the /logout endpoint.

You can test this by logging in with an incognito/private browsing window, or by clearing the cookie before clicking the login button the second time.

Comment: From https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication, I need to specify prompt=none to log in via silent authentication, while I am not, see https://github.com/ocdexperience/auth0-example/blob/master/App.js#L58. Also, I do utilize /logout, see https://github.com/ocdexperience/auth0-example/blob/master/App.js#L82. Lastly, since my app is a react-native (expo) app, I don't have incognito/private browsing window option. Can you help me understand what do I miss?

Comment: Can you try adding `prompt=login` or utilize `max_age` like mentioned here: https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-enforce-re-authentication-for-sensitive-operations/6056

Comment: I think neither works for me. I tried prompt=login and it turns out I will have to login every single time, even though I don't logout explicitly. Also, from the documentation of max_age, I don't think it fits my goal.

My goal: after a user logins, until he explicitly logout by calling /logout API, or the session timeouts, otherwise auth0 should allow the user to log in without having to go through the prompt -> select google account -> login flow again.

Meanwhile, if the user explicitly logout, the next time he logins he should have to go through the flow again.